# if such $a_{n+1}=\frac{n^2 a_{n}+a^2_{n}}{a^2_{n}+2a_{n}-n}+1$ use without indcution find $a_{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

solve following sequence without induction:

.Let $a_{1}=1$ and such 
$$a_{n+1}=\dfrac{n^2 a_{n}+a^2_{n}}{a^2_{n}+2a_{n}-n}+1$$
Find the $a_{n}$

I have solve $$a_{2}=\dfrac{1+1}{1+2-1}+1=2,a_{3}=3,a_{4}=4$$
so we have 
$$a_{n}=n$$
becasue use   induction.we have 
$$a_{n+1}=\dfrac{n^3+n^2}{n^2+n}+1=n+1$$

Comment: I think you have somewrong

Comment: No,$$a_{2}=\dfrac{1^2\cdot 1+1}{1^2+2-1}+1=2$$

Comment: Oh yes, replotting.

Comment: @ConĐườngNghệ Your formula is correct, don't worry. Why do you want to do this without induction?

Comment: because I think  this  sequence result maybe exist nice explain